# Using microsoft flow - sending email with attachment when specific field is modified in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have a sharepoint list which is for safety inductions. Currently when someone submits their safety induction they can choose Yes/No to which aspects of training have been covered and then once submitted it will go to approval based on the Trainer E-mail they have put in the Person field.

With the Yes/No parts I want to set up a Flow which will send an email with an attachment with a competency assessment with a Q and A which covers aspect of that training. For example if they have chosen Yes to Electrical Safety then they will be sent an email with the competency assessment attachment for Electrical Safety from the document library on the same page.

Is this currently possible with Microsoft Flow and Sharepoint Online? I can set it for an entire item but not for a single field.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done using flow with below steps.

1. Add trigger for item modified.
2. Add action to get item from same list with item ID returned as dynamic output of step 1.
3. Add condition check the field value.
4. Add action to send E-Mail.

Answer (score 1):

1   Lets Goo

- The flow can be tested by adding a list and creating a flow by
  clicking Flow from the Menu
- O365 email id will be used to configure email functionality (you can use Outlook email as well)
- The list items contains an attachment on each rows – this can be
  enabled by selecting List settings -> Advanced settings -> select
  “Enabled from Specify whether users can attach files to items in this
  list”.
- lets make it mandatory that each list item contains an attachment -
  for this test

  - Making use of the primary column ‘ID’ to refer each row of the list
    in this Flow
- LETS HAVE A LOOK NOW WITH AN EXAMPLE

The flow has been created on a list called Student which got 3 columns (Title, Student Name, Class) 
[image]

•   The flow can be created directly by clicking on the Flow button as shown in the image above, Select the type of event were the user needs to send email, here we are using the following option to send once the user adds a new record.
[image]

•   The initial flow will looks like **when a new item is created** and this will be the starting point of your Flow

•   Start designing the Flow by using Get Attachments action, give the Site Address, List Name (Name of the list were we are attaching Flow )and ID which is the unique identification for rows in list
[image]

•   Get the attachment content activity and fill the details 
[image]

•   Send email functionality will come inside the Get attachment content to get it linked with the content, click on 
**Add an Action** Button to achieve this.
[image]

- Send an Email (select Outlook 365/select Outlook) activity we need to
  provide the recipients email address and Subject .
- In the Body part we can include the list fields by adding the
  appropriate one using search option
- Select the Attachments Name-1 and select the field you want to
  display (here we are using the Display Name from Get Attachments
  activity)
- Attachments content section needs to be have Attachment content from
  the Get Attachment Content activity
- The Flow is ready to Save now, click on

Save Flow

The completed flow will looks like following:-

[image]

[image]

- Add a new entry and attach a file to see whether the email triggers –
- Email from O365 outbox
  [image]

Hope this would help ....Enjoy !!!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but what if I have added more than one attachment, then in this case will it send out multiple emails?