# Email Attachment in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, flow

In SharePoint online, is there a way to send attachment with email on item created in List/Library.
By using MS Flow ?
JSOM Code?
SharePoint Designer Workflow?

No third party tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in SharePoint online it is possible to send an attachment with email using Microsoft Flow.

Follow the steps given in below links:

1. [Using microsoft flow - sending email with attachment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223145/using-microsoft-flow-sending-email-with-attachment-when-specific-field-is-modi)
2. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-and-SharePoint-Send-Email-with-Attachment-unreadable/td-p/129955

Comment: I found the solution myself, but thank you for sharing.